# Create table not exist error "Operand should contain 1 coulmns"

Tags: mysql, sql

I checked some questions regarding this error and most of it experience this error on using "SELECT" function but in my case I am using CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST but experience this error, can you check my code to see what causes the error or if you guys know other way to do the same stuff.

I want to create a table for yearly payment actually that is supposed to be monthly but I am trying by year right now.

```
/* INSERT HERE THE LIST OF ALL EXISTING PAYMENT TABLES */
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS T_distinctTable; 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T_distinctTable (
ctr int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
DisTable varchar (18)
);
INSERT INTO T_distinctTable (DisTable) 
SELECT TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'cams' and TABLE_NAME like concat ('%','Payment_20','%');

SET @endYearTemp = (select count(*) from T_distinctTable); 

set @YearNow = (SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()));

set @TableName = concat('Payment_',@YearNow);

set @SQLTable = ('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `', @TableName ,'` id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name CHAR(30),PRIMARY KEY (id)');
        SELECT @SQLTable;
        PREPARE stmt FROM @SQLTable;
        EXECUTE stmt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concat()` to concatenate strings. Putting them in parenthesis and separate them with commas alone wouldn't do it. And you forgot the parenthesis around the column definitions of `CREATE TABLE`.

```
...
set @SQLTable = concat('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `', @TableName ,'` (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name CHAR(30),PRIMARY KEY (id))');
        SELECT @SQLTable;
        PREPARE stmt FROM @SQLTable;
        EXECUTE stmt;
...
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice my simple mistake, I think I need to get some sleep, thank you again for the help sticky bit

Comment: I think its too late I cannot delete it right now :(